# Create Wordpress plugin to store twitter post

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have written this code. I am successfully getting the data through twitter but I am not able to connect to the database. I need to store the data to the SQL DB.
Apache Port- 82
MySQL port- 3308
I am getting error no 2005

```
<?php include "twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php";

define ("DB_USER","root");
define ("DB_PASSWORD","root");
define ("DB_HOST","localhost:3308");
define ("DB_NAME","rwh-1");
define ("DB_SOCKET","/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock");
/**
*Plugin Name: Basic Plugin
*Plugin URI: http://www.google.com
*Author: Vivek Kumar
*Description: Displaying twitter's handle tweet.
*Version: 1.0
*/

$dbc =mysqli_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD");

function do_something(){
    //do something


?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label>Search :<input type="text" name="keyword"/></label>
        </form>
<?php

$consumer = "****";    
$consumercecret="****";
$accesstoken="****";
$accesstokensecret="****";

$twitter =new TwitterOAuth($consumer,$consumercecret,$accesstoken,$accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=@imsrk&result_type=recent');

       if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
            $tweets=$twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$_POST['keyword'].'&lang=en&result_type=recent&count=100');

            foreach($tweets as $tweet){
                foreach($tweet as $t)
                {
                    if($t->text!=null)
                    {

                        $query="INSERT INTO handletweet (name, tweet) VALUES (\"".$t->user->name."\",\"".$t->text."\")";

                       if(!$dbc)
                       echo ('Failed to connect to Mysql: '.mysqli_connect_errno($dbc).' <br><br>');                           

                        $stmt =mysqli_prepare($dbc,$query);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        $affected_rows=mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

                        if($affected_rows == 1)
                            echo 'Name: '.$t->user->name. ' 1' .'<br>' .$t->text.'<br><br>';
                            else
                            echo 'Name: '.$t->user->name.' 0' .'<br>' .$t->text.'<br><br>';


                        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                        mysqli_close($dbc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}

add_action('the_content','do_something');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mention port.

Use this:

`define ("DB_HOST","localhost");`